# Can .Net run on Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: raspberry-pi, .net-micro-framework

Raspberry Pi 2 has been released and is supporting Windows 10.

May seem like a stupid question, but if it supports Win 10, can .Net run on the system? Anyone know any alternative options if it cannot?

Thanks,

Comment: you can always run C# code with Mono

Comment: Thanks, had a look - thats useful

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you asked this question few months ago, .NET Framework source codes have been opened to public community by Microsoft. Before that, there's a project called **mono** which is an open-source framework like .NET for Linux. The purpose behind the development is to provide a **common-language-runtime** (CLR) environment via successfully implementing **common-intermediate-language** (CIL) specification standards. Now, mono project still proceeds and it also supports OS X too. According to your question, yes. You can develop .NET programs on both Linux and Windows 10 by using **mono** or Microsoft **.NET Framework**.